# How to include property to span tag GridView yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I define a cell of table by below script:

```
'attribute' => 'status',
'format' => 'html',
'value' => function ($model) use ($bgStatus) {
    $status = Constant::$status['background'][$model->status];
    return Html::tag('span', $status, ['class'=>'label '.$bgStatus[$status], 'data'=>['id'=>'1', 'ds'=>'123']]);
},
'label' => 'Status'
```

And no have any changes. 
I'm looking for the span tag will contain property as

```
data-id="1" data-ds="123"
```

What are my wrongs?

Comment: What is being returned at the moment?

Comment: @Lynch: Only `<span class="label label-success">Assigned</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot, that should return what you're after

```
'attribute' => 'status',
'format' => 'raw',
'value' => function ($model) use ($bgStatus) {
    $status = Constant::$status['background'][$model->status];
    return Html::tag('span', $status, ['class'=>'label '.$bgStatus[$status], 'data-id'=>'1', 'data-ds'=>'123']);
},
'label' => 'Status'
```

Comment: Can you check that the `$status` and `$bgStatus` values are set just to be sure they're not causing the errors. The code above works fine for me and generates exactly what you've asked for

Comment: Tks for your response, but all working normal, except `data-id` and `data-ds`. I also tried `style`, but not work

Comment: Try changing the `format` attribute to `raw` instead of `html`, that may do the trick

Comment: Yeah, right way! I done! Tks @Lynch. It looks like Yii 1.x

Comment: No problem, happy to help